# How to create pivot tables based on external data with Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi, pivot-table

Does anyone know how to work with Apache Poi to create a pivot table based on external data (csv or resultset)?
I have worked with С# and ADODB before and used this:

```
ADODB.Recordset rs = new Recordset();
rs.Open(cmd, Type.Missing, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenForwardOnly, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockReadOnly, 1);
Excel.PivotCache pc = wb.PivotCaches().Add(
Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlExternal
, Type.Missing);
pc.Recordset = rs;
```

The last string set resultset to a pivot cache.
How can I do it using Apache POI (or maybe something else in Java)?

Thanks.

Comment: Google it first. There is a whole bunch of questions/guides regarding that topic

Comment: There's almost nothing about external data and apache poi's pivot tables. So this is why I'm here

Comment: There is everything you need. Everything is external data, unless you hardcode the values

Comment: Dont answer me pls